# Storing jwt in httponly cookie requires both frontend and backend apps to be on the same domain (MERN)

Tags: deployment, jwt, mern, samesite, cookie-httponly

So i have implemented a mern stack app with JWT stored in httponly cookie.
So in development mode, both frontend and backend are on the same domain (localhost,different ports), and everything works fine.
When i deploy both apps ( ex: vercel) , so each app will have its own domain name (or subdomain like .vercel.app) , the troubles begins:

The  `Samesite` attribute of httponly cookie will prevent the cookie from being stored since both apps are cross origins.

So i have tried this:

- setting it to `Strict` or `Lax` will prevent Set-cookie from storing the cookie since both apps have different domains.
- setting it to 'None' : the first problem is that with this value the cookie can be accessed by other origins, the second problem is that google chrome for example will prevent set-cookie from storing cookie automatically.

So im looking for a solution or any other implementation to solve this issue.

Comment: Consider making the cookie [partitioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies) rather than `SameSite=None`.